# Filtered index is not used when variable in WHERE condition

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, filtered-index

Why MS SQL Server refuse using supporting filtered index in this scenario?

```
-- demo data
CREATE TABLE #Test (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Test_ID PRIMARY KEY
    ,Col1 NVARCHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()
    ,Col2 NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT N''  -- !!
    );

WITH
    L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS O), -- 2 rows
    L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B), -- 4 rows
    L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B), -- 16 rows
    L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B), -- 256 rows
    L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B), -- 65,536 rows
    L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B), -- 4,294,967,296 rows
    Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS N FROM L5)
INSERT INTO #Test(Col2)
SELECT TOP 100000 N''
FROM Nums;

INSERT INTO #Test(Col2)
VALUES(N'ABC');

-- FILTERED index to support filter predicate of a query
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Test_Col2_filtered ON #Test (Col2 ASC) WHERE Col2 <> N'';

-- just checking statistics
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('#Test', 'IX_Test_Col2_filtered')

-- condition on variable = index scan :-(
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(20) = N'ABC'

SELECT Col1
FROM #Test
WHERE Col2 = @Filter
    AND Col2 <> N'';
```

[image]

Everything goes as expected when using literals.

```
-- condition on literal value - index seek + key lookup :-)
SELECT Col1
FROM #Test
WHERE Col2 = N'ABC';
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtered indexes can't use variables/parameters, unless you're building your query with dynamic SQL so that the query ends up getting executed with a literal.

A good article on the topic is [Filtered Indexes and Dynamic SQL](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/filtered-indexes-and-dynamic-sql/) by Jeremiah Peschka.

**OR**

As Martin suggested, you could add `WITH (RECOMPILE)` to the query, but that should not be used without understanding the potential repercussions (see [RECOMPILE Hints and Execution Plan Caching](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/12/recompile-hints-and-execution-plan-caching/)).

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if there is any "official" documentation telling this fact?

Comment: @jerik1 Generally *how* execution plans are derived doesn't make it into the documentation. Presumably because its crazy complex and changes often. I suppose the better wording should be "The engine can't use filtered indexes with..." since the filtered index still exists and works if the engine chooses it.

Comment: it can do if you use OPTION (RECOMPILE) so it can sniff the variable value and also doesn't have to compile a plan suitable for any variable value

Answer (score 0):

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('Test', 'IX_Test_Col2_filtered')
```

When you use constant value in filter then `Optimizer` make plan specific for that value.
Since `Optimizer` know the `parameter` value,it use the `Statistics Histogram` to estimate the number of records that can be returned by a query.

When Local Variable is use in where condition, `Optimizer` make plan for "`OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`".
It do not use `Statistics Histogram`,it uses the information on the `Density Vector`.

```
`All Density* Number of rows` which is equal to `1*100001`
```

So Number of rows to read will be `100001`.

As we know in cost base optimization ,`Optimizer` will choose cost effective plan quickly.

So choosing index will not be feasible for `Optimizer`.

If you `Index Hint` then it will use `Index Seek` but cost will be more.

Optimizer make plan for `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` because when next time you change value for `local variable` then it will reuse same plan.

In same case it is beneficial and in some case it will hurt performance.In `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` assumption is based on calculation 
`All Density * Number of rows`.

Now I create Proc ,

```
Create Proc TestProc
@Filter NVARCHAR(20)
as

Begin

SELECT Col1
FROM #Test
WHERE Col2 = @Filter
    AND Col2 <> N'';

End

Exec TestProc N'ABC'
```

Verify the plan, plan is exactly similar to `(dynamic)sp_executesql` .

We see `Index seek` and `key look up` .

```
No of Execution=1
Estimated Number of rows=1

when you write dynamic sql,

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(200) = ''
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(20) = N'ABC'

set @Sql='SELECT Col1
FROM Test
WHERE  Col2 <> N''''
AND Col2 = @Filter1';

    print @Sql
    execute sp_executesql @Sql,N'@Filter1 NVARCHAR(20)',@Filter
```

`sp_executesql` is a Proc .
Variable `@Filter1` exactly behave like parameter of Proc.
`sp_executesql` is not using `@Filter`.

So `optimizer` make plan for that parameter.When you pass some other value it will reuse same plan.This is called `Parameter sniffing`.

So basically what I said is correct.

Comment: I am aware of OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN with variables. But the number of rows in index is 1 not 1M, so the assumption should be 1 row

Comment: @jerk, Read my edited now.

Comment: ) I didn't get where you heading. For me your answer is out of topic.

Comment: @jerik1 , No hard feeling.I was trying to answer "Why MS SQL Server refuse using supporting filtered index in this scenario?" .I do not much agree with the link given.May be my language is little poor,but I am confident with the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative pattern, place the variable to lookup into a temp table and join, try the following with execution plans and statistics io on

```
DECLARE @Filter NVARCHAR(20) = N'ABC'
DECLARE @FilterT TABLE (
    f nvarchar(36)
)
insert into @FilterT select N'ABC'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FilterT
CREATE table #FilterT (
    f nvarchar(36)
)
insert into #FilterT select N'ABC'

SELECT Col1
FROM #Test
WHERE Col2 = @Filter
    AND Col2 <> N'';

SELECT Col1
FROM #Test
WHERE Col2 = N'ABC';

select col1
from #Test
inner join @FilterT
    on #Test.Col2 = [@FilterT].f
    AND Col2 <> N'';


select col1
from #Test
inner join #FilterT
    on #Test.Col2 = [#FilterT].f
    AND Col2 <> N'';
```